# Cannot convert String array to Int array from core data and sum it in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I have 2 question. First, I can't convert String array to Int array from core data

```
let sum = recordFilter.map{$0.amount!.dropFirst()} //["9.99", "6.58"]
let intSum = sum.map({Int($0)})  //[nil, nil]
```

My array format:

```
[<Record: 0x600000099fa0> (entity: Record; id: 0xd0000000003c0000 <x-coredata://913F25A5-B2C9-4646-9091-5EFE7F906908/Record/p15> ; data: {
    accountbook = "first book";
    amount = "\U00a59.99";
    assest = nil;
    category = "\U6295\U8d44";
    createdAt = "2017-11-16 16:00:00 +0000";
    date = nil;
    id = 15;
    recordtype = "\U6536\U5165";
    remark = "";
    toAccBook = nil;
}), ...})]
```

Second, I want to sum it by `.reduce` but I got `Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(Int, _)'` How to fix it?

```
let sum = recordFilter.map{$0.amount!.dropFirst()}.reduce(0, +)
let intSum = sum.map({Int($0)}).reduce(0, +)
//Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(Int, _)'
```

Comment: `Int` is integer without decimal places. The strings do have decimal places and even seem to start with a linefeed character in the record. Why do you use a string type for a numeric value anyway?

Comment: Oh thanks! I changed it to Float already, it works. how about the sum error? @vadian

Comment: You're apply reduce to string as int in first line. Just use it in second line not in first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, I can't convert String array to Int array from core data

From the description of [init?(_ description: String)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2927504-init)

> The string passed as `description` may begin with a plus or minus sign character (+ or -), followed by one or more numeric digits (0-9)

`9.99` is an invalid format for an `Int` which is probably why the map that tries to do the conversion is returning nil for each element.

If you do this:

```
let doubleSum = sum.map({Double($0)})
```

You'll get close to what you want but the elements of the array will be optionals.

> Second, I want to sum it by .reduce but I got Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(Int, _)'

The problem is that the constructor returns an optional. One way to fix this would be to unwrap the optionals but make `nil`s zero for the purpose of the addition.

```
let doubleSum = sum.map{ Double($0) ?? 0.0 }.reduce(0, +)
```

you'll get what you want. The `??` unwraps the result of the string to double conversion, using 0 where the conversion fails.

Or, even better, as Martin R suggests, you can use flatMap to eliminate the need for `??`.

```
let doubleSum = sum.flatMap{ Double($0) }.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: I found that it will get nil when the double value is above thousand. Is there any way to increase the limit? @JeremyP

Comment: @WanJern That sounds weird. Do your strings have separators every three digits?

Comment: @WanJern @Raphael has a point, if you have a value `1,234.00`, the normal conversion routine will break because of the comma.

Comment: @WanJern in such a case, it's better to use a [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) to do the string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate explicit types for your variables to check if you are coding what you think you are. My guess is you are used to dynamic languages; it doesn't work that way here.

`recordFilter.map { ... }` creates a `String`, so `reduce` needs a pair of parameters of types `T` and `(T, String) -> T`, respectively. With `T == Int`, it's looking for `+: (Int, String) -> Int` which does not exist.

Note that if you fix that, `sum` is either `String` or `Int` (not sure what you want), to neither of which applying `map` does what you want it to do, by my estimation.